# Recorrer una hoja línea a línea en VBA y obtener datos como array

Tags: excel, vba, macros

Estoy intentando iterar una hoja de excel a través de vba. Necesito que lea línea a línea una hoja para tener un array con cada celda, hasta encontrar la línea vacía (final).

Pongo un ejemplo de datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sé que habrá datos de la columna A a la G, lo que no sé es el número de líneas que habrá.

La idea es:

```
Sub importarDatos()


 '
 ' importarDatos Macro
 ' 
 '
 Dim lineas As Worksheet
 Set lineas = Worksheets("Lineas")

End Sub
```

Me creo una macro, la cual obtiene la hoja. (Hasta aquí bien).

La pregunta es: ¿Cómo puedo obtener los datos de esa hoja en una Matriz desde A1:G1 hasta An:Gn para luego poder recorrer esa matriz con un bucle?

Necesitaré en cierto momento saber el número de línea que estoy leyendo, para escribir los datos en otra hoja (exportar los datos) en la misma línea. Es decir, cada línea de la hoja a leer, escribirá 1 línea en una nueva hoja.

PD: La hoja a leer se encuentra en la ubicación dónde voy a ejecutar la macro. Es decir, pulsando un botón (eso sé hacerlo), llamará a la macro que leerá la hoja de ese Workbook e importará en otra hoja los datos.

Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Y definir el rango hasta la columna 7, pasarlo al array y luego iterar en el array?

```
Dim RangoDatos as Range
Dim ArrayDatos as Variant
Dim is as integer

Set RangoDatos = lineas.Range("A2:G:" & lastRow)
ArrayDatos = Rangodatos

For i = 0 to Ubound(RangoDatos)

'aqui metes el código que necesites para procesar los datos

Next i
```

Cargar un rango en un array apenas consume tiempo e iterar por él lo mismo. Depende del número de filas que tenga a lo mejor te compensa.

Answer (score 0):

Parece que la solución no era muy difícil.

Rebuscando en internet, me he dado cuenta que podía obtener la última línea escrita, por lo tanto, a partir de ahí, puedo hacer un bucle para ir  obteniendo cada una de las líneas de la siguiente manera:

```
    Sub importarDatos()


 '
 ' importarDatos Macro
 ' Importa los datos copiados al archivo de la macro
 '
 Dim lineas As Worksheet
 Dim last As Integer
 Dim actual As Integer
 Dim lineaActual As Variant
 ' Seleccionamos la hoja a abrir
 Set lineas = Worksheets("Lineas")
    ' Obtenemos el número de elementos máximo en la hoja
    lastRow = lineas.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    lastCol = 7
    ' Creamos las distintas líneas
    For i = 1 To lastRow
        ' Obtenemos la fila como Variant
        lineaActual = lineas.Rows(i)
        ' Procesamos los datos aquí
        ' Cambiamos el número de línea actual
        actual = i
    Next
End Sub
```

Lo más óptimo sería recoger hasta la columna 7, para no traer todo el archivo cada vez que lee una línea. Habría que mirar cómo hacer eso.

Comment: Ramon, haz lo que te dice @dogwall en su respuesta porque iterar línea a línea  consume un tiempo absurdo. Lo mejor es delimitar el rango que quieres y hacer que en tu caso `lineaActual = rangoceldas.Value` o incluso, si lo que quieres es la hoja entera: `lineaActual = lineas.UsedRange.Value` (La propiedad UsedRange coge todo el rango que se ha usado en la hoja, vigila porque si has tenido datos y los borras, cogerá esas filas en blanco).